# DepthFirstSearch in binary tree using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am cuurently learning pointer arithmetics in C
as an exercise I would like to program a binary tree

so far i got the structure itself

```
typedef struct bintree
{   struct bintree *left;
    struct bintree *right;
    int value;
} bintree ;
```

the constructon of the tree

```
bintree *new_bintree (int value)
{   bintree *node = malloc(sizeof(bintree));
    knoten -> left = NULL;
    knoten -> right = NULL;
    knoten -> value = value;
    return (node);
}
```

the add node function

```
int bintree_add(bintree *tree, int value)
{   if (value == tree->value)
    {return(-1);}
    if ((value <= tree->value)&&(tree->left!=NULL)) /*Left node check and insert*/
        { return(bintree_add(tree->left, value));}
    if ((value <= tree->value)&&(tree->left==NULL))
    {bintree *knoten = malloc(sizeof(bintree));
        knoten -> left = NULL;
        knoten -> right = NULL;
        knoten -> value = value;
        tree -> left = node;
        return(0);
        }

    if ((value >= tree->value)&&(tree->right!=NULL)) /*right node check and insert*/
        { return (bintree_add(tree->right, value));}
    if ((value >=tree->value)&&(tree->right == NULL))
    {bintree *knoten = malloc(sizeof(bintree));
        knoten -> right = NULL;
        knoten -> left = NULL;
        knoten -> value = value;
        tree -> right = node;
        return (0);
    }
}
```

and the clear function

```
void delete_bintree(bintree *tree)
{
    if (tree->left != NULL)
    {delete_bintree (tree->left);}
    if (tree->right != NULL)
    {delete_bintree (tree->right);}
    free(tree);
}
```

now i would like to implement the DepthFirstSearch and the BreathFirstSearch

This is my so far code for the DFS

```
bool bintree_dsearch(bintree *tree, int value)
{   
    if (value == tree->value)
    {return true;}
    if (tree->value == NULL)
    {return false;}
    if (tree->left != NULL)
    {return bintree_dsearch(tree->left, value);}
        else return bintree_dsearch(tree->right, value);

}
```

any help is appreciated :)

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some code that you've worked on and where you are having problems. There are several resources available on the internet to get you started, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal contains pseudo code for both kind of traversal, which can adapted and implemented to fit your needs.

Comment: added code for my DFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok fixed it and now it is running fine

here's the code

```
bool bintree_dsearch(bintree *tree, int value)
{
    if (value == tree->value)
    {return true;}
    if (tree->value == NULL)
    {return false;}
    if (tree->left != NULL)
    {return bintree_dsearch(tree->left, value);}
    if (tree->right != NULL)
    {return bintree_dsearch(tree->right, value);}
}
```

Comment: What did you change to fix it?

Comment: the else statement in first post was totally wrong
also didnt check if there is a right node and then perfomed the recursive seach for the value